# Two exercises in function composition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am struggling with these two problems, sorry for any formatting errors as this is new to me, thanks.

1. Let $f(x) = -4x-5$ and $g(x)=-2x-6$. Find $(f \circ g)(3)$.
2. Let $f(x) = -2x-7$ and $g(x)=-4x+3$. Find $(f \circ g)(-5)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2x$. Do you know what $(f\circ g)(x)$ and $(g\circ f)(x)$ will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an example will help you figure out how function composition works.

If $$f(x) = x^2-2$$ and $$g(x) = \sqrt{x+2}$$ then $$\begin{align} (f\circ g)(x) &= f(g(x)) \\ &= f(\sqrt{x+2}) \\ &= (\sqrt{x+2})^2-2 \\ &= (x+2)-2 \\ &= x\end{align}$$ and $$\begin{align}(g \circ f)(x) &= g(f(x)) \\ &= g(x^2-2) \\ &= \sqrt{(x^2-2)+2} \\ &= \sqrt{x^2} \\ &= |x|\end{align}$$

So then $(f\circ g)(2) = 2$ and $(g \circ f)(2) = |2| = 2$.  BTW $(f\circ g)(x)$ won't always equal $(g\circ f)(x)$ -- that's just how it turned out with this example.

Comment: I think this may be more confusing than helpful, given you introduce $|x|$ and you compute $(g\circ f)(2)$ instead of $(f\circ g)(2)$. I think it's pretty apparent OP is struggling with something very fundamental. But who knows...maybe it will prove useful.

Comment: I added $(f\circ g)(2)$ as well.  Also hopefully OP knows that $|x|$ can be defined as $\sqrt{x^2}$, but if not, now he should. :)

Comment: +1 for taking the effort. It saddens me when OP posts a question and doesn't bother to respond to comments and the like. Clearly this OP is not here to learn, just to get answers.

Comment: nope i am here to learn =) I am plugging in the number for the inside variable equation first and then putting in my solution from that to the outside equation. so i get 43 for the first and -53 for the 2nd. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Julie That's right.  Good job.

Comment: @Julie Glad to see you're back and taking the time to learn :) You have three good answers now. This one shows you how to compute compositions with a concrete example(s), Bernard's addresses a more conceptual outlook, and my new one addresses your problem specifically, confirming your own answers. Good job on getting it done correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to know the definition:
$$(f\circ g)(x)\overset{\text{def}}{=}f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)$$
i.e. you first compute $y=g(x)$, then use the result to compute $f(y)$.
This procedure may be symbolised by the following diagram:
$$x\overset{g}{\longmapsto}g(x) \overset{f}{\longmapsto}f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) $$

Answer (score 0):

Just to "finish this problem off," more or less, consider the following for the first and second problems, respectively.

---

For the first problem:
\begin{align}
(f\circ g)(x) &= f(g(x))\\[0.5em]
&= f(-2x-6)\\[0.5em]
&= -4(-2x-6)-5\\[0.5em]
&= 8x+19.
\end{align}
Hence, $(f\circ g)(3)=43$.

---

For the second problem:
\begin{align}
(f\circ g)(x) &= f(g(x))\\[0.5em]
&= f(-4x+3)\\[0.5em]
&= -2(-4x+3)-7\\[0.5em]
&= 8x-13.
\end{align}
Hence, $(f\circ g)(-5)=-53$.